# Is masturbation adharma? Doesnt it form a part of purushartha (kama)?

Tags: bhagavad-gita, dharma, brahmacharya, kama, purushartha

It is against principles of Brahmacharya. But is it against dharma?

Comment: Hi. Welcome to HSE.!! Please visit [How does a new user get started on Hinduism SE?](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33/how-does-a-new-user-get-started-on-hinduism-se), to get familiar with our site. Further, kindly have a look at: [What topics can I ask about here?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Have an enriching Journey ahead.

Comment: To be honest, why are mods allowing such questions? In my honest opinion, it is just degrading the site.